# error: installing Microsoft AspNet Identity Owin in vb 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net

I cant install Microsoft AspNet Identity Owin in vb 2010 using NuGet

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the Microsoft ASP.NET Identity Owin targets the .Net framework 4.5 and you are using 4.0.

You can must upgrade your projects to .Net 4.5 to use this package.